# Need help with a measure within Mozart's 'Rondo alla Turca'

Tags: piano, notation

In the 21st measure of Mozart's *Rondo alla Turca*/Turkish March (3rd movement of K. 331), there's a trill in the treble clef that I can't quite get right. Would you be so kind to expand the measure as plain notes, so I know when to coordinate the base chords with the trill please?
[image]

Comment: This section of K. 331 is better known as "Rondo Alla Turca". If someone could update this accordingly, would probably be helpful.

Comment: @Noldorin: You should be able to suggest an edit by clicking the `edit` button.

Comment: @Ben: Oh, I didn't think I had priveleges at my meagre reputation! Seems you're right.

Comment: @Noldorin: Anyone can *suggest* an edit regardless of rep. (But 2000 is still the threshold for unreviewed editing.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be played somewhat like this:

[image: typeset music]

Note that the trill should not necessarily be played exactly in time, but this should show you where it begins and ends.

Comment: Two minor quibbles: while there is nothing to say that the trill should be played as 32nd notes, it is in practice about the fastest you can play it a the piece's tempo (unless you're a rather accomplished pianist). Also, be sure to gie a slight emphasis to the final A. (Trills are ornaments and should rarely be brought out in a piece.)

Comment: Good point; that's what I had tried to say in my final point. (I couldn't think of a better way to notate it. Also, this way it aligns with the two printed 32nd notes, which is probably desirable.)

Comment: Yeah, fair point. It does at least elucidate the timing. :-) I might just put an accent mark on the previously-mentioned note, though it's probably non-trivial in whatever program you're using to generate the score notation. (How did you generate that image for that matter? It looks pretty nice.)

Comment: I tried practice this on a tempo of 100 and it was incredibly hard. I can barely do it in 80. When the piece is played at its real tempo of about 120, this seems impossible. Is this part played fully in a serious performance?

Comment: There should not be a "gap" before the final "A-B" note pair. The trill must end on B so that it proceeds smoothly (stepwise) to the A. @AmericanLuke's answer is correct, also because trills in Mozart start on the note above the principle melodic note — B, in this case.

Answer (score 15):

I agree with the speed of the trill in Ben's answer, but [this](http://www.oldflutes.com/articles/classicaltrill/index.htm) documents the fact that Mozart started his trills on the upper note (either directly or suspended). This is further proven by the fact that skipping directly from C to A is both unnatural and unlikely. Here is how it should be played:
[image: Trill as played]
Starting on the upper note leaves us to end on the B, leaving a smooth step to the A. Note, the first C of the trill should be tied to the crotchet.